# Facebook share image shows only on second time

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I copy a link of my website and paste it on Facebook the image in preview window is loading, but for few seconds facebook give up and there is no picture. But if I refersh facebook site and paste it second time everything is ok, the image shows. How can I solve this problem? I have many sites, and each have another image.

The og tags looks like this:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://zlapgrafika.pl/images/works/839878/110898/zlapgrafika_532c3e54b5b3a.png">
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://zlapgrafika.pl/images/works/839878/110898/zlapgrafika_532c3e54b5b3a.pn">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://zlapgrafika.pl/konkursy/projekt/numer/110898">
```

Comment: It's probably unrelated, but you're missing the `g` from `png` at the end of `og:image:secure_url`.

Comment: Don't think that 1.9MB is a large file (2000 X 2000 PX) for an OG image? your current image is extremely large!

Comment: I have the same problem.. Have you solved it eventually?